# Adding pins onto a Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following block of code which adds pins including descriptions and links onto a Google map. How can I refactor it so that I can add pins easier and without so much redundant code?

```
var map;

function initializeMap() {
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.2340464046899, -71.0956621170044),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    scrollwheel: false
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.2340464046899, -71.0956621170044),
    map: map,
    title: "Pin 1",
    url: "#tabs-pin1"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs('select', marker1.url);
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9584457, -70.6672621),
    map: map,
    title: "Pin 2",
    url: "#tabs-pin2"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs('select', marker2.url);
```

```
var marker9 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.445921, -71.2690294),
    map: map,
    title: "Pin 9",
    url: "#tabs-pin9"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker9, 'click', function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs('select', marker9.url);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is extract one function that will form the marker from the parameters and them call it as many times as markers count is:

```
var markers = [];    // probably you don't need this array
function CreateMarker(lat, lng, markerTitle, markerUrl)
{
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    title: markerTitle,
    url: markerUrl
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs('select', marker.url)
});

markers.push(marker); // you can omit this step if you are not going to work with markers after
}

function initializeMap() {
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.2340464046899, -71.0956621170044),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    scrollwheel: false
};

CreateMarker(42.2340464046899, -71.0956621170044, "Pin 1", "#tabs-pin1");
// repeat this call for every marker
}
```

Comment: I think you missed a ); after the second block.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry, updated the code.